# Database SQL Counting Query Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a generic database with generic information implemented inside. The query I need to do involves a relation with the following attributes: Account_number, Balance, BranchID, Account_Type and Account_Rate.

Now, the query I need to make counts the account_type(Which there are 3: Saver, Student and current) and says how many there is in each branch using the attribute branch id as one of the primary relations.

For example I have the following query:

```
Select account_type, branchid, count(*) from accounts where account_type="Student"
```

It returns a table with account_type= "Student" with the one of the branchids 600533 and says there is two in the third attribute. This is correct there is two student accounts in branch 600533. I need it however do it for every branch id (3 branches) and every account_type.

I can see I just need to expand on this however I am not coming up with anything useful.

How could I overcome this?

Comment: "I need it however do it for every branch id (3 branches) and every account_type. " the query result is already going over all branches. To apply the query to all account types, remove "account_type="Student".

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I would of thought the same however it only returns one tuple with account_type as student, only one branch ID and the count which counts all of the accounts which is 6. Strange...

Comment: Try this: Select account_type, branchid, count(*) from accounts Group by account_type, branchid

Comment: Brilliant! Such a simple add to make it work. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not grouping by the the columns you're counting.
The following should work:

```
SELECT account_type, branchid, count(*)
FROM accounts
-- WHERE account_type="Student"
GROUP BY account_type, branchdid;
```